# Windows Runtime equivalent to WriteableBitmap's AddDirtyRect

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime

I'm building an app where I would like to redraw the image on screen around a user's finger touch. [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) has a method [AddDirtyRect(Int32Rect dirtyRect)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.adddirtyrect.aspx) to indicate to indicate changes my code has made to the back buffer so that the whole image needn't be redrawn. Its Windows Runtime equivalent, the [Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br243259) class, does not.

Can I tell the system which part of the screen to redraw as the result of code changing a Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap?

Comment: Are you seeing some performance issues with just calling `Invalidate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this API isn't there. You could use a secondary patch bitmap to update only a portion of the rendered output. If you need more control over what gets pushed out to the buffers you'd need to use a `SwapChainPanel` and DirectX.